# Rails display formatted date in words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I have the date in this format 2014-04-05 gotten from @post.date
I want to convert it to this format "Saturday Apr 5" in my view.
And if the date is today, i want it use this format "Today Apr 6"
Currently i have

```
<% if @post.date === Date.today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %>
   <p> Today Month(short form) Day(number) </p>
<% else %>
   <p> Day(word) Month(short form) Day(number)  </p>
<% end %>
```

How do i go about formatting the dates?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
<% if @post.date === Date.today %>
   <%= @post.date.strftime("Today %b %d") %>
<% else %>
   <%= @post.date.strftime("%A %b %d") %>
<% end %>
```

Refer to **[complete list of format directives](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)** available for `strftime`.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner solution would be to implement this as a helper method in "app/helpers/application_helper.rb"

Define the method as such:

`def date_string_for(datetime)
    datetime.strftime("%b %e, %Y")
 end`

Then from any view you can call:

```
<%= date_string_for @post.date %>
```

This provides a DRY solution.